# How to construct the missing gaps?

Tags: modeling

I am very new to Blender and trying to adjust a scoliosis brace for my neuromuscular scoliosis. There is already a brace that I use in my routine and wanted to make some adjustments to it and then 3d print it. I scanned the brace but as expected it is not perfect. The point I am stuck on right now is **how can I fill these gaps perfectly according to the existing shape of the brace**. Thanks

[image: Brace image]

Comment: Hi. For someone new to 3D modelling this would be quite a challenge with so much of the data missing. Even for someone skilled this would be a challenge as the "perfect" shape would be left up to the artist to interpret. Can you try and get a better scan?